# Why mocked method with pytest-mock does not return_value?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have found [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/02/16/how-to-write-independent-unit-test-with-pytest-and-mock-techniques/) a more concise way to mock methods. But, when I run pytest, I get

> orig_width, orig_height = image_reader.getSize()

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

This is test_tdd.py

```
def test_get_image_x1(mocker):
    """Test half size image."""
    # This works but it is longer
    class Mock_class:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            pass
        def getSize(self):
            return 1, 1
    mocker.patch("tdd.get_image.ImageReader", return_value=Mock_class())

    mocker.patch("tdd.get_image.Image")

    get_std_aspect_image(Path("tests/python-logo.png"), size="x 0.5")

    tdd.get_image.Image.assert_called_once_with(
        "tests/python-logo.png", width=0.5, height=0.5
    )


def test_get_image_x2(mocker):
    """Test half size image."""
    # This does not work
    mock_image_reader = mocker.patch("tdd.get_image.ImageReader")
    mock_image_reader.getSize.return_value = 1, 1

    mocker.patch("tdd.get_image.Image")

    get_std_aspect_image(Path("tests/python-logo.png"), size="x 0.5")

    tdd.get_image.Image.assert_called_once_with(
        "tests/python-logo.png", width=0.5, height=0.5
    )
```

test_get_image_x1 works, test_get_image_x2 does not because no values is returned from ImageReader.getSize

Tested function:

```
def get_std_aspect_image(file_name: Path, size: str = "x1"):
    """Return Image with original aspect and given width."""
    try:
        image_reader = ImageReader(str(file_name))
    except OSError:
        logging.critical("OS Error reading %s", file_name)
        raise

    orig_width, orig_height = image_reader.getSize()
    aspect = orig_height / float(orig_width)

    pattern = re.compile(r"(width|w|height|h|x)\s*(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", re.IGNORECASE)
    result = pattern.search(size)

    if result is not None:
        if result.groups()[0].lower() in ("w", "width"):
            width = float(result.groups()[1]) * mm
            return Image(
                str(file_name),
                width=width,
                height=(width * aspect),
            )
        elif result.groups()[0].lower() in ("h", "height"):
            height = float(result.groups()[1]) * mm
            return Image(
                str(file_name),
                width=height / aspect,
                height=height,
            )
        elif result.groups()[0].lower() == "x":
            factor = float(result.groups()[1])
            return Image(
                str(file_name),
                width=orig_width * factor,
                height=orig_height * factor,
            )

    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup of the mock needs to more closely match how it is used. Since the code under test calls the ImageReader class, so must you.

That is, instead of:

```
mock_image_reader.getSize.return_value = 1, 1
# do
mock_image_reader().getSize.return_value = 1, 1
#                ^^
# or more properly, use .return_value to avoid the class mock capturing the call eg.
mock_image_reader.return_value.getSize.return_value = 1, 1
```

The mocking code uses one mock for the class ImageReader, and another for the instance that it produces. If you want to specify the behaviour of the "instance" mock then you need to use `()` or `.return_value` to get access to it. Otherwise, you specifying the behaviour of the class mock.